# How to select specific column types in SQLite3?

Tags: ios, swift, database, sqlite, select

```
PRAGMA table_info(myTable)
```

This query selects all the info in a table, for example: if there are 2 columns in a table then this query will select all the column names, column types e.t.c

I just want add one clause i.e I want to get info of specific columns that I define in the query.

Like this:

```
PRAGMA table_info(myTable) where columnNames = 'a' and columnNames = 'b' // this is wrong query but I just mentioned it to make my question more clear.
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `pragma_table_info()` in a query with a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM pragma_table_info('myTable') -- note the single quotes
WHERE name IN ('a', 'b') -- equivalent: name = 'a' OR name = 'b'
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qQBTMkwJC5Q2uAvtcdUyav/0).

Comment: @RehanAliKhan `name` is the name of the column in the results that contains the column's name.